# Differentiate between :focus via tab-key and :focus via click in CSS

Tags: css

Although I am quite certain that the answer to my question will be "Can't be done" I'd like to be sure and ask you guys here.

I have a rather typical scenario in which I want to enable tabbing through my website (i.e. using tab key on keyboard). The item the user has just tabbed upon should be marked visually via CSS. So far, so good. This, obviously, demands the focus-pseudo class:

```
a {
    color: #000;

    &:hover {
        color: lighten(#000, 10%); // discreet change
    }

    &:focus {
        background-color: green; // extreme change
    }
}
```

But I want to apply this style solely when the user tabs through the page. When the user hovers or clicks an element the style should be something different.

Example: A user hovers or clicks an anchor. Then the visual aid can be discreet because the user already knows which element he has interacted upon. But when he tabs through the page he can not be so sure and thus the styling should be more drastic.

The problem I am having is: An element gets the focus-styles applied on on both tabbing the page and clicking on it.

Is there a CSS-only way to apply styles solely when an element got focused via tabbing?

Again, I am pretty sure that this is not possible, but just to be sure I have asked the question.

Comment: Ever get any resolution on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:focus` pseudo-class does not discriminate based on how the element entered focus in the first place. So indeed, this is not possible with just CSS. At the very least you'd need to annotate the element on focus via an event handler.

The `:hover` and `:active` pseudo-classes won't be of any help here since the former only applies when the mouse pointer is on the element and the latter only applies when the mouse button is down, i.e. neither state persists the way `:focus` does, since an element remains in focus even after the mouse pointer has left the element, making it indistinguishable from an element that received focus via tabbing.

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I thought. I'll leave the question open a bit longer but I doubt there'll be other answers here...

Answer (score 10):

There's a new CSS selector `:focus-visible` that is intended to solve this scenario by targeting only the elements that were focused via keyboard input.

This is only supported natively in Firefox today, however there is [a polyfill](https://github.com/WICG/focus-visible) that makes this possible in all browsers through a `.focus-visible` class name.

Answer (score 1):

Just so to list this as an alternative answer (which I also chose, tbh):

One can also work with javascript to disable the mousedown-event. This event is not really that useful, the click-event still works and it prevents the clicked element from getting the focus-state. This, in turn, makes using the :focus property in CSS useful again as it now only triggers when the user navigates that element via tab key.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck with pure CSS so I wrote a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/filipetrovic/baq6bL9s/):

```
var allowTabFocus = false;

$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  $('*').removeClass('tab-focus');
  if(e.keyCode === 9) {
    allowTabFocus = true;
  }
});

$('*').on('focus', function() {
    if(allowTabFocus) {
    $(this).addClass('tab-focus');
  }
});

$(window).on('mousedown', function() {
    $('*').removeClass('tab-focus');
  allowTabFocus = false;
})
```