# Styling an element selected by TAB navigation

Tags: css

I currently have a dropdown menu. It contains several `li`'s, and if it has a dropdown, this `li` contains an `ul`, containing one or several `li`'s again.

The part that's important for this question is this.

```
li ul {
    display: none;
}

li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This works fine with hovering. However, I'm trying to make my website fully navigable without a mouse. The way you would navigate a menu without a mouse is by using the `TAB` key, however, I can't seem to get the dropdown to show.

I tried using `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus`, which were the only 3 options I could come up with.

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS? If not, what is the fastest way (page loading time) to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus a `li` element by default since it's not interactive by default, so without modifying the HTML this is impossible in pure CSS.

But you can apply your rule to `li:focus > ul` if you add a `tabindex=0` attribute to each of your top-level `li` elements:

```css
li > ul {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > ul, li:focus > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li tabindex=0>Item<ul><li>Subitem</ul>
  <li tabindex=0>Item<ul><li>Subitem</ul>
  <li tabindex=0>Item<ul><li>Subitem</ul>
</ul>
```

Unquoted, `tabindex=0` is just 11 bytes per `li` element, or 13 if you're uncomfortable with unquoted attribute values, so the effect on page load should be negligible.

Keep in mind that making your `li` elements focusable also allows them to receive focus from a mouse click, so clicking one with the mouse causes its submenu will remain visible until it loses focus. [You cannot prevent this with pure CSS either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282841/differentiate-between-focus-via-tab-key-and-focus-via-click-in-css/43283017#43283017)

Comment: The dropdown does show up. However, when I'm trying to navigate to one of it's subs (I added tabindex to them as well), it hides the dropdown again and thus the sub is not selected anymore

Comment: @InzeNL: Yeah... that's definitely going to be a problem, since :focus doesn't apply to ancestors the same way :hover does. Given these limitations you'll need a script, but I wouldn't worry about the extra HTTP request (assuming you don't already have a script for your site and need to make one).

Comment: Could you give me an indication of what this script would look like?

Comment: @InzeNL: I'll have to get back to you on that as it's late here - I thought it'd entail simply listening for focus/blur events on li[tabindex] elements but based on some testing, unless I'm doing something wrong it seems to be more complicated than that...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but there are a couple of things to be aware of.

1: you need to use `tabindex`, as @BoltClock states above

2: You can only do it with a menu and submenu, if you have three levels it won't work

3: You can't use `display: none;` to hide it, as it's not transitionable.

In the `onfocus` event handler, you add a class, say - `.myfocus`. For extra points you can toggle the class, so if it's clicked on while active it will become inactive.

In the `onblur` event handler you just remove the class. This would hide your submenus immediately, so to get it to work you need to add a short pause before your transition kicks in, to give the browser time to register the click.

It's mostly done in CSS and HTML, but you would need to write a couple of event handlers. These are only going to be a line of code each so shouldn't impact on site load times.